# Get Time Format 'minutes, seconds' (for example: 12,56 (12 minutes and 56 seconds)

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I would like to sum the amount of minutes and seconds, so that you get the total minutes and seconds in a format of 12,56. Does anyone know what kind of SQL-code I need to get this kind of format?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server. I forgot to mention that!

Comment: @Rdongen . . . Your question specifies "sum", but you accepted an answer with no "sum" in it.  I still don't understand what you are really asking.  A good question should be unambiguous and sample data and desired results usually help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sql server you can use datepart() to get the minute and second from any date, time or datetime value:

```
select concat(datepart(minute,getdate()),',',datepart(second,getdate()));
```

To convert milliseconds to minutes and seconds:

```
declare @milsec as int
set @milsec=1000000
select RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(second,(select @milsec/1000.0),0),108),5)
```

But if total value is more than 60 minutes that will be ignored since that will be in hour part.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to convert milliseconds to this format?